# What is a tail trap in html

Tags: html

I found some weird markup in the end of a web page, could someone please tell me what is this for?

```
    </body>
</html>
<!--tailTrap<body></body><head></head><html></html>-->
```

It's a Chinese website: http://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MjM5ODMwMzExNQ==&mid=2651714590&idx=1&sn=bfdfeda82219e580807ea2c701b3d695&scene=0#wechat_redirect

Comment: Looks like opening/closing tags for a dynamic page to me.  However the code is commented our so it's not actually doing anything.

Comment: Seems rather bizarre. Can you share where you found this.

Comment: It can be a markup added by a library used in the website

Comment: Also I am unable to find anything at all in regards to `html tailtrap`, and it looks like it's an internal name that the developer used.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I've added the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some attackers use something like lastIndexOf() to find the string "`</body>`" and insert scripts before that, without checking if the string is commented. With this trap, the inserted will not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Wechat page, which is the most popular app in China.
The tags is for prevent html hijacking.

Comment: how does it prevent html hijacking?

Comment: Normally, html hijacking search html tags and injects scripts, these tags can cheat it.

Comment: could you please offer an example of such attacking techniques?

Comment: I' m sorry to say that i just know few about it.

Comment: @ospider, Some attackers use something like lastIndexOf() to find the string "</body>" and insert scripts before that, without checking if the string is commented. With this trap, the inserted will not work.

Comment: @kellyxiepei wow, that do make sense, maybe you could post it as an answer?